# Doctrine2 association property order with a name "almost similar" entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I went through a strange "bug".

I have 2 associations on an entity with "almost the same same" :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\Parametres", mappedBy="collecteur")
 */
private $parametres;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\ParametresEdition", mappedBy="collecteur")
 */
private $parametresEdition;
```

When lazy loading happens, I got the exact same object `TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\ParametresEdition` in both properties `$parametres` and `$parametresEdition`.

But when I reverse the associations :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\ParametresEdition", mappedBy="collecteur")
 */
private $parametresEdition;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\Parametres", mappedBy="collecteur")
 */
private $parametres;
```

Everything is working perfectly. I get the correct object for each association.

Is it caused by the fact that the entities are named almost similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you made a mistake on the owning side? What do the column definitions on other side (inside `Parametres` and `ParametresEdition`) look like? You don't show them in your question.

You probably have twice `inversedBy="parametres"` or `inversedBy="parametresEdition"`.

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\Collecteur", inversedBy="????")

@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TaxeApprentissage\Entity\Collecteur\Collecteur", inversedBy="????")
```

Comment: My bad ! You are right. I was focusing on inverse side and the mistake was on owning side.
Thank you Wilt.